# Do I need to re-render PayPal's Smart Button on select change?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a select element on my page. This select element chooses different variations of a product. All these products cost the same price, but I would like to indicate on the invoice which product was selected. I am using PayPal Smart Button to integrate checkout on my page. Let's say I have the following:

```
<select id="product-select">
    <option value="product-A" selected> Product A </option>
    <option value="product-B"> Product B </option>
    <option value="product-C"> Product C </option>
</select>

<div id="paypal-button-container"> </div>

<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '50'
          },
          items: [{
            unit_amount: {
                value: '50'
            },
            quantity: '1',
            name: 'Product A',
          }],
        }],
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

When a user changes the selected option to Product B or Product C, do I need to re-render the PayPal button on select change? If so, how do I dispose of the old one?

Answer (score 1):

Rerendering only needs to be done if the `currency` or `intent` or similar query string parameters from loading the SDK change. That is why they are part of the SDK line, because those things need to be known on render.

Other things, like the amounts and contents of the order, can be calculated when a button is clicked. That is when the createOrder function is called.  So you can use `document.getElementById().value` or similar to populate the data you're going to use when creating the order.

......

If you were going to re-render (not needed here), this is how you would do it:

Instead of calling .render() immediately, first save a reference to the object...

```
var myButton = paypal.Buttons({...});
myButton.render('#paypal-button-container');

// things happen, user makes changes that require re-rendering the buttons
myBytton.close();

// render the buttons again here
// if query string parameters to the SDK change, the SDK needs to be reloaded
```